# How to grep a specific line with quotes and then compare something inside it

Tags: shell

I have many files that contain strings like:

```
code="AA123",code_mark="AI123"
code="AA234",code_mark="AI234"
code="AA456",code_mark="AI456"
code="AA789",code_mark="AI789"
code="AA321",code_mark="AI321"
code="AA111",code_mark="AI111"
code="AA222",code_mark="AI221"
```

The prefix AA and AI should be always like that in the line but there are some cases where `code_mark="AA###"` instead of `code_mark="AI###"`. I want to find those lines, e.g.:

```
code="AA451",code_mark="AA451"
code="AA121",code_mark="AA121"
code="AA272",code_mark="AA272"
```

I tried for multiple hours to do it but the only thing I have achieved was to grep the text in between the brackets. Is there any way to grep all the lines that do not match the above pattern?

Comment: `between the brackets` [Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) are not [quotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark), did you mean quotation marks? `compare the cases where AA is not equal to AI?` You want to compare [case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case) of letters? Could you explain what exactly do you want to compare? Please post sample files content. Please post what would you want to get on output - filenames? Or lines contents? Or both? Why not just grep for `code_mark="AA` like `grep 'code_mark="AA'`?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant double quotes "". I would like both , I would like to have as an output all the cases that do not match the initial logic AA AI for instance, code="AA123",code_mark="AA123",code="AA567",code_mark="AA567", code="AA789",code_mark="AA789" ecc..

Comment: So `grep 'code="AA[0-9]+",code_mark="AA[0-9]+"'`? You can learn regexes at https://regexcrossword.com/ and it's definitely a tool that will come in handy.

Comment: Yes thats what I was looking for, unfortunately when I launched it doest return anything. I launched like this grep 'code="AA[0-9]+",code_mark="AA[0-9]+" ' file*

Comment: I tried only the first part without the comma and didnt work either I had to use egrep 'code="AA[0-9]+" ' file* maybe because in the file between the code and code_mark there is an actual comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grep`, like so:

```
grep 'AA.*AA' input_file(s)
# or:
grep -v 'AA.*AI' input_file(s)
```

Example:

Create input file:

```
cat > in.txt <<EOF
code="AA123",code_mark="AI123" (this is on one line)
code="AA234",code_mark="AI234" (this is on one line)
code="AA456",code_mark="AI456" (this is on one line)
code="AA789",code_mark="AI789' (this is on one line)
code="AA321",code_mark="AI321" (this is on one line)
code="AA111",code_mark="AI111" (this is on one line)
code="AA222",code_mark="AI221" (this is on one line)
code="AA451",code_mark="AA451" (wrong case)
code="AA121",code_mark="AA121" (wrong case)
code="AA272",code_mark="AA272" (wrong case)
EOF
```

Find the desired lines:

```
# Lines that have 'AA' followed by 'AA':
grep 'AA.*AA' in.txt

# or:

# Lines that do not have 'AA' followed by 'AI':
grep -v 'AA.*AI' in.txt
```

Prints:

```
code="AA451",code_mark="AA451" (wrong case)
code="AA121",code_mark="AA121" (wrong case)
code="AA272",code_mark="AA272" (wrong case)
```

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

Comment: thanks but what if in the file AA and AI are always the same but the numbers change everytime meaning it can be AA123 AA234 AA321 AA442

Comment: @MarcoPolo I am not sure I understand your comment. It would be helpful for me and others who can answer your question if you edit the question with a few more cases of input and desired output. Please include the cases of input **and** the desired output that you refer to in your comment.

Comment: sure, I have edit my initial message to make it more clear :)

Comment: @MarcoPolo The input example is now clear, thank you. But what is the desired output **example** that corresponds to **this** input example? It is still not clear, sorry...

Comment: no worries , I updated with the desidered output. Ideally would be also cool to know from which file the wrong case come from because I have a list of 10 files.